# Cucmber Unable to open debugger port from intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, cucumber, remote-debugging

I am running Cucumber from Intellij on a remote machine and get:
Unable to open debugger port (x.x.x.x:37955): java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"

JVM options -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=${8787},server=y,suspend=y

and it generated port 37995

the IntelliJ configuration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyQTo.png)

I can see the remote is listening to the port and it is open on the remote machine but when running from IntelliJ I get Unable to open debugger port (x.x.x.x:37955): java.net.ConnectException "Connection timed out: connect"
the same procedure is working if trying to debug from Jsystem

Comment: Can you telnet to this port? Check that IntelliJ IDEA connections are not blocked by the local firewall.

Comment: No I get timeout error as well

Comment: Check your firewall settings, it may be blocking the  connections to the remote.